# How do I pull in a range of cells from another workbook in Excel that meet a certain criteria?

Tags: excel

I have an excel worksheet.  In this worksheet it has a list of course ids and corresponding info (ie size, title, etc).  These course IDs are different depending on the department offering them.  For example one department they all begin with 76, another they all begin with 64.  I want to have another worksheet in this excel file where I can click a button or enter a value into a cell and it will pull all the courses that begin with 64 for example into this other worksheet.  How do you do that?

EDIT:  I have tried to do this Range("A5").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="36*" but it doesnt see the asterick as a wildcard and gives me zero results even though I have a few courses that stat with 36...

EDIT2:  OK I figured out that excel sees my course ids a numbers which is why I cannot use the wildcard search above.  When I do the wildcard search on text fields it works OK.  How do I change the data in excel so it sees it as a text filter?  I have tried going in and modifying the data so the type is Text instead of General but it still is not letting me use the wildcard.

EDIT3:  OK I am just going to filter it as a number ie Range("A5").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=36000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<37000"  Though I would love to know how to change the filter from text to number....

Comment: have you tried vlookup
https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function

hope this helps

Comment: That gives me only one cell though, I want all courses that begin with 64 to be listed.  I basically want the second worksheet to be the same as if I went to the first and manually filtered the course id to begin with 64.

Comment: VBA - use a filter and a wildcard `*` in your criterion.

Comment: I have tried that I have put Range("A5").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=36*  but it does not work I get the filter turned on but it shows no results.  I have tried to put the 36* in quotes as well and it also does not work :(

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question with what you've tried, otherwise it's likely to be closed.

Comment: OK i updated it.  I also discovered that the wildcard is not working because excel sees the course ids as numbers not text.  I have changed them to text in the workbook but for whatever reason it still sees them as numbers, do you know how to make excel look at this column as text and not number?